# Tool to distinguish the paper citation by type

Tags: publications, citations, bibliometrics, tools

I was always interested in whether there is any tool that allows you not only to count the citations of your paper (e.g. Google Scholar) but also distinguish the citations by their quality or by how actually important the reference to your specific work was in the new paper.

The possible distinguishing types could be:

1. Your paper is just cited as one of the others in the related works section of a new paper
2. Your paper serves as one of the significant examples the author gains inspiration from
3. The new paper is a direct derivative of your existing paper

I know about Altmetric but it solves the problem from another side, calculating the impact via third-party sources, like social networks, which is also actually quite interesting but not what I am interested in.

Comment: Related: [How to find only the papers that cite a particular article in an important way?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/40612/17254)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantic scholar ( https://www.semanticscholar.org/ ) offers something along these lines.

It counts

- Highly Influential Citations
- Background Citations
- Methods Citations
- Results Citations,

and if you make a profile there you will receive notifications when your papers get cited, and when potentially interesting papers related to your work gets available online/detected by semantic scholar.

Lately the algorithm has improved considerably, so I get immediately notified about pre-prints that should have cited my papers but they didn't :), but also when my papers get cited.